# How do I get data from One HTML page to update the Another page on submit

Tags: javascript, html

I have two html files book.html and receipt.html. I want to use the data entered from the book.html form to update receipt.html.

my code worked when i had both form and receipt in the same page. I want the submit button to open a new page with the receipt. how do i do this using just javascript.

this is my js code

```
function alertName(){
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var destination = document.getElementById("destination");
    var realD= destination.options[destination.selectedIndex].text;
    var dat = document.getElementById("date").value; 
    var location = document.getElementById("locate");
    var realL=  location.options[location.selectedIndex].text;  
    document.getElementById("disp-name").innerHTML= name;
    document.getElementById("disp-date").innerHTML= dat; 
    document.getElementById("disp-location").innerHTML= realL;
    document.getElementById("disp-destination").innerHTML= realD;
    document.getElementById("disp-email").innerHTML= email;
}
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', alertName);
```

Comment: You can use "localStorage" to store data in one page and use it later in different  pages

Comment: Where is form being submitted to?

Comment: @charlietfl this is the code i have on my button.  `<button id="button" type ="button" target="framename" onclick="location.href='receipt.html';">Submit</button>`

Comment: That completely ignores all the form data. Doesn't make sense creating a receipt for a transaction that isn't saved anywhere

Comment: @Nusrath i tried using local storage like this 

`if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined") {
        var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
        localStorage.setItem("name", name); }





function alertName() {
            var upd = document.getElementById("disp-name").innerHTML; upd =localStorage.getItem(name);}` still not working

Comment: @charlietfl how else do i work around this? can i save this data with just js?

Comment: Yes in localStorage but would only be accessible by that user. If it is an actual commerce transaction you need to send it to a server to be stored

Comment: okay thanks. It's working now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To know more about [LocalStorage](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp)

I store values in LocalStorage and retrieve it later when it needed.

Below is my code to store data in one HTML page:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>HTML Forms</h2>


  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" value="Mickey">
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" value="Mouse">
  <br><br>
 <button onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>



<script>
function myFunction() {

// Check browser support
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
  // Store
  localStorage.setItem("lastname", document.getElementById("lastname").value);
  localStorage.setItem("firstname", document.getElementById("firstname").value);
    console.log("Storaged successfully")
    location.href = "C:/test2.html";
}
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

And retrieve it in another HTML page:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onload="myFunction()">

<h2>HTML Forms</h2>

  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname">
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname">
  <br><br>




<script>
function myFunction() {

// Check browser support
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
  // Retrieve
  document.getElementById("lastname").value = localStorage.getItem("lastname");
  document.getElementById("firstname").value = localStorage.getItem("firstname");
    console.log("Retrieved successfully")
}
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Hope this help :)

Comment: Thank you very much. StackOverflow is a wonderful community!

Worked like magic!!!!

Comment: Okay  I will. can i combine the js codes on both html files in one file?

Comment: Why are using 2 html files if you want 2 js files in one html. Just hide one page HTML onclick show another html file .